Proof of Trace Inequality with Nilpotent Matrices?
I have a conjecture on a trace inequality about a positive-definite, symmetric matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$ and a 'conveyor belt' matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$:
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 \\ &\vdots  & &\ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I have numerical support that:
\begin{equation}
Tr[PD^{-1}P^TD] \geq \sum_{m=1}^{M-1}\frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_{m+1}}
\end{equation}
Where $\{\lambda_m\}_{m=1}^M$ are the eigenvalues of $D$ sorted in increasing order. Can you prove it?
It somehow feels a bit like Ruhe's trace inequality...
(I'm especially interested if techniques to prove this help in proving another question I have: Proof of Conjecture on `Block-Orthogonalisation Always Reduces Trace')

No, the result is as stated, the conveyor belt does not loop, the dimensions just get dumped at the end!

Got it, thanks! (For the record, my question was if the bottom left entry of $P$ should be $1$ instead of $0$.)

standard terminology would be to call $P$ a nilpotent companion matrix or companion matrix for $x^n$.  The use of "permuted" in the title strongly suggests the companion matrix for $x^n-1$ not $x^n$.

Fair enough, will change! Let me know if it is still bad

An attempt is needed here otherwise this will likely be closed for missing context. I suspect any answer will involve machinery outside your grasp but in any case I will give you a big hint: write out the eigenvalues for $D^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\geq \frac{1}{\lambda_2}\geq \cdots \geq \frac{1}{\lambda_{M}}$ and the eigenvalues of $P^TDP$ as $0=\sigma_1\leq \sigma_2\leq \cdots \leq \sigma_{M}$ then argue $\text{trace}\Big(D^{-1} (P^T D P)\Big)\geq \frac{\sigma_2}{\lambda_2}+\cdots +\frac{\sigma_m}{\lambda_m}$  then argue the pointwise bound $\sigma_k\geq \lambda_{k-1}$ for $k\geq 2$

Lol, thank you for the helpful, if slightly rude, hint

To complete @user8675309's hints into an answer:
Define $C=P^T D P$. Clearly, $(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $0$. Moreover, $x^T C x = (Px)^T D (Px) \ge 0$ for all $x$, so $C$ is positive semi-definite matrix. Therefore, its eigenvalues are of the form $0=\sigma_1 \le \sigma_2 \le \cdots \le \sigma_M$. Now, by Ruhe inequality, we have
$$
\mathrm{tr}(D^{-1} C) \ge \sum_{m=1}^M \frac{\sigma_m}{\lambda_m} = \frac{\sigma_2}{\lambda_2} + \cdots + \frac{\sigma_M}{\lambda_M}.
$$
Now, let us compare the eigenvalues of $C$ and $D$ using the Poincare separation theorem (aka Cauchy interlacing theorem). It is convenient to define $C'$ as the nonzero $(M-1)\times (M-1)$ block of $C$ and $P'$ as the $M \times (M-1)$ matrix obtained by removing the first column of $P$. It is clear that $C' = P'^T D P'$ and $P'^T P' = I_{M-1}$. Moreover, the eigenvalues of $C'$ are $\sigma_2 \le \cdots \le \sigma_M$. Therefore, we have
$$
\lambda_1 \le \sigma_2 \le \lambda_2 \le \sigma_3 \le \cdots \le \sigma_M \le \lambda_M.
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathrm{tr}(D^{-1} C) \ge \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} + \cdots + \frac{\lambda_{M-1}}{\lambda_M}.
$$

Great, thank you! :)
